# JSON schema validation for documents with new keys inserted into them

Tags: json, mongodb, schema, jsonschema

I am trying to create json schema for my non SQL database (mongoDB in this cast), and I have collection that I can insert keys into. Meaning:
doc:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"version 1": {
    "vector1": [],
    "vector2": []
}
}
```

Insert to document "version 2" key:

doc:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"version 1": {
    "vector1": [1,2],
    "vector2": [0,0]
},
"version 2": {
    "vector1": [1,1],
    "vector2": [0,0]
}
```

And I can insert more versions with varying names to the same document.
How would I got about creating a schema for such such a thing?

Comment: You can possibly use the [embedded document pattern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/#embedded-document-pattern) with each _version_ as an array element.